# ctypes structure, byte alignment

Tags: python, ubuntu, ctypes

I am using ctypes module to define a C like structure.

```
    class AtomPayload(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [ ("address",    ctypes.c_uint8,  8),
             ("mask",       ctypes.c_uint8,  3),
             ("regL",       ctypes.c_uint8,  5),
             ("regH",       ctypes.c_uint8,  1),
             ("rw",         ctypes.c_uint8,  1),
             ("reserved",   ctypes.c_uint8,  6),
             ("param1",     ctypes.c_int32, 16),
             ("param2",     ctypes.c_int32, 16),
             ("param3",     ctypes.c_int16, 16)]
```

But the size of this structure have different result in Windows and Ubuntu.

In Ubuntu, the output is 10, while it is 9 which is what I want in Windows. Anyone knows how to make it also work in Ubuntu. Does not the attribute *pack* work in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I test your example (on ubuntu) like this:

```
import codecs
p = AtomPayload()
p.param1 = 0x1111
p.param2 = 0x2222
p.param3 = 0x3333
print(codecs.encode(bytes(p), 'hex'))
```

It produces:

```
b'00000011110022220000'
```

I'm not sure what exactly is going on here, this could be a bug in ctypes. Maybe a problem caused by the unaligned bitfield.

Anyway, having a 32 bit bitfield split into two 16 bit integers seems unnecessary to me, this should produce the same result:

```
class AtomPayload(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = [
             ("address",    ctypes.c_uint8,  8),
             ("mask",       ctypes.c_uint8,  3),
             ("regL",       ctypes.c_uint8,  5),
             ("regH",       ctypes.c_uint8,  1),
             ("rw",         ctypes.c_uint8,  1),
             ("reserved",   ctypes.c_uint8,  6),
             ("param1",     ctypes.c_int16, 16),
             ("param2",     ctypes.c_int16, 16),
             ("param3",     ctypes.c_int16, 16)]
```

Now I get:

```
b'000000111122223333'
```